# error when installing ObjectAid on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-juno, objectaid

I am trying to install `Objectaid` for Eclipse Juno 4.2.1. I did all steps found on the [Installation from ObjectAid Documentation](http://www.objectaid.com/installation) but still having this error:

```
An error occurred while installing the items
session context was:(profile=profile,    phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null -->     [R]com.objectaid.uml 1.1.5, action=).
Failed to prepare partial IU: [R]com.objectaid.uml 1.1.5.
```

I've done `Help > Install New Software > Available Software Site` and then remove `ObjetAid UML Explorer` but it didn't work. **So I am wondering if there is another thing I can do to achieve the installation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experiencing the same problem on 4.3.2 (Eclipse Kepler).

```
An error occurred while installing the items session context was:
(profile=epp.package.standard, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]com.objectaid.uml 1.1.6, action=).
Failed to prepare partial IU:
[R]com.objectaid.uml 1.1.6.
```

So I searched the solution for a couple of hours (while this post was being über garbage collected) and I found the answer:

- I had a broken update of the Eclipse Plataform due to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=427148

After successfuly updating the platform, I just repeated the steps above and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue, then I downloaded the newest version of eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2). The installation of ObjectAid happened smoothly post it. I compiled the steps [here](http://evverythingatonce.blogspot.in/2016/04/tech-talk-reverse-uml-generator-in.html) reference.

Answer (score 0):

ObjectAid Plugin can be installed from the below link - steps to be followed included. enter link description here Note : use http://www.objectaid.com/update/current as most people mention to use http://www.objectaid.com/update instead which will not work.